# How do I pass a computer name as a variable to the PowerShell -ComputerName from a batch file?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have been searching for the right answer without success.

I have a batch file that executes a PowerShell Script.

Batch file is;

```
PowerShell C:\scripts\GetStatus.ps1
```

PowerShell Script that works is;

```
Get-Service -Name svcUdpLogger -Computer Name server01 | Start-Service
```

What I am looking for is how do I pass the server01 as a variable into this script from a batch file.

Depending on if a server service has stopped, this batch file would be run automatically to restart this service.

I have tried using the following;

```
param([string]$computername=)
```

I keep getting invalid argument.

Thanks,

UPDATE - I think I have solved it. This may not be the correct way to do it, however it does work this way;

```
PowerShell C:\scripts\GetStatus.ps1 -ComputerName server01
```

If there is a  more elegant way to do it, I would appreciate the clarity!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue was with the way you were calling the script.

If you want to get fancy:

```
 param([string]$computername)

 if ($computername) { 
    Write-Host "Starting Service on: $computername"

    try {
        Get-Service -Name svcUdpLogger -ComputerName $computername -ErrorAction Stop | Start-Service -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "...Service Started"
    } catch {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Host "...Error Occurred Starting Service: $ErrorMessage"
    }

 } else {
    Write-Host "Computer Name Not Passed on the Command Line"
 }
```

And Call it like:

```
PowerShell C:\scripts\GetStatus.ps1 HostName
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I did not realize that I could write the PowerShell script with C#/Java type coding.

This was very helpful.